# Using GROUP BY and OVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the total sales grouped by year and country. This works as expected:

```
SELECT Year, Country, SUM([Total Sales])
FROM Table
GROUP BY Country, Year;
```

Then, I have to compare the contribution of each country to the total sales in a year. I did this:

```
SELECT Year, Country, SUM([Total Sales]),
    SUM([Total Sales]) OVER(PARTITION BY Year) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Country, Year;
```

Which gives me this error:

> Column 'Table.Total Sales' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to nest the sums:

```
SELECT Year, Country, SUM([Total Sales]),
       SUM(SUM([Total Sales])) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Country, Year;
```

This syntax is a little funky the first time you see it.  But, the window function is evaluated *after* the `GROUP BY`.  What this says is to sum the sum of the total sales . . . exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you can't aggregate at the query level with the `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` and at a windowed level with your window function. The reason for this is that the Windowing function takes place on the result set after everything else has been applied to it, including the `GROUP BY`. At that point in time the column `[total sales]` only exists as a non-aggregated field in the original table, so you kind of end up with nonsense. You can aggregate first in a subquery, and then do your windowing on top of that:

```
SELECT Year, Country, Total_Sales, SUM([Total_Sales]) OVER(PARTITION BY Year)
FROM
(
    SELECT Year, Country, SUM([Total Sales])     
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Country, Year
) sub
```

Comment: Your first sentences are misleading, because you can combine window functions and aggregation functions without using subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do it without GROUP BY clause the following way:

```
SELECT 
  Year, 
  Country, 
  SUM([Total Sales]) OVER (),
  SUM([Total Sales]) OVER (PARTITION BY Year) 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error, you need to add the column present windowed aggregate function in `Group by` but that will make the aggregation wrong.

If you want to find the contribution of each `company` per `year` try something like this

```
SELECT year, 
       country, 
       Sum([total sales]), 
       OA.year_total, 
       ( Sum([total sales]) / NULLIF(OA.year_total,0) ) * 100 AS Percent_contribution 
FROM   table 
       OUTER apply (SELECT Sum(b.[total sales]) AS year_total 
                    FROM   table b 
                    WHERE  a.year = b.year) OA
GROUP  BY country, 
          year, 
          year_total;
```

`Outer Apply` here will calculate the total sum of each `year`. We can use the total sum to find the contribution of each company

Another way using `JOIN`

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT b.year, Sum(b.[total sales]) AS year_total 
         FROM   table b 
         GROUP  BY b.year) 
SELECT year, 
       country, 
       Sum([total sales]), 
       b.year_total, 
       ( Sum([total sales]) / NULLIF(b.year_total, 0) ) * 100 AS Percent_contribution 
FROM   table a 
       JOIN cte b 
         ON a.year = b.year 
GROUP  BY year, 
          country, 
          b.year_total
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
 SELECT distinct Year, Country, SUM([Total Sales]) OVER(PARTITION BY Country, Year) sumbycountryyear, SUM([Total Sales]) OVER(PARTITION BY Year) sumbyyear
 FROM Table
```